# Why do I get an Assertion Error when patching a class with unittest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

When I patch a method directly using unittest.mock.patch, I can use the mock.assert_called_with() function to correctly assert whether that method was called with certain values. However, when I patch a class directly, any asserts I use on the class itself or any of the class methods come back with "AssertionError: Not Called" even though the class and methods are called.

There are examples in the unittest documentation of successfully patching a class and using assertions: [unittest mock doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

Here is my test with the SiteMetaData class methods patched directly and EdgeAPIRoutes class patched:

**Test**

```
    @patch("repo.routes.EdgeAPIRoutes")
    @patch("repo.site_meta_data.SiteMetaData.get_repo_type")
    @patch("repo.site_meta_data.SiteMetaData.get_edge_api_inputs")
    def test_get_route_list_repo_interface_edge(self, mock_edge_api_inputs,
    mock_get_repo_type, mock_edge_api_routes_class):
        """
        Test that SiteMetaData.get_route_list is used 
        appropriately and returns expected values from 
        mock as a valid response object
        """
        from usecase import interface
        from usecase import request_objects
        from usecase.response_objects import ResponseSuccess
        from utils.utils import DatetimeString

        all_filters = {"filters" : {"parent_company" : "parent_1",
                                    "site" : "site_1",
                                    "start_date" : DatetimeString("2020-01-01 00:00:00.000"),
                                    "end_date" : DatetimeString("2020-05-01 00:00:00.000")
                                    }
                    }

        example_route_list = [
                            "route_1",
                            "route_2",
                            "route_3"
                        ]

        edge_inputs = {
                        "edge_site" : "edge_site_name",
                        "edge_key" : "ffff-ffff-ffff"
                    }

        error_response = None

        mock_edge_api_inputs.return_value = [
                                                edge_inputs["edge_site"], 
                                                edge_inputs["edge_key"], 
                                                error_response
                                            ]

        mock_get_repo_type.return_value = [
                                            "Minestar Edge", 
                                            error_response
                                        ]

        mock_edge_api_routes_class.get_route_list.return_value = [
                                                                    example_route_list, 
                                                                    error_response
                                                                ]

        resp = interface.get_route_list(request=request_objects.RouteList.request_wfilters(all_filters))

        mock_get_repo_type.assert_called_with(all_filters["filters"]["parent_company"],
        all_filters["filters"]["site"])
        mock_edge_api_inputs.assert_called_with(all_filters["filters"]["parent_company"],
        all_filters["filters"]["site"])
        mock_edge_api_routes_class.get_route_list.assert_called_with(all_filters["filters"]["start_date"], 
        all_filters["filters"]["end_date"])
        mock_edge_api_routes_class.assert_called_once_with(edge_inputs["edge_site"], edge_inputs["edge_key"])
        self.assertTrue(bool(resp))
        self.assertEqual(resp.type_, ResponseSuccess.SUCCESS)
        self.assertEqual(resp.value["routes"], example_route_list)
```

**Method**

```
def get_route_list(request):
    """
    """

    interfacelog.info("running get_route_list")

    if bool(request):
        repo_type, repo_type_error = site_meta_data.get_repo_type(request.filters["parent_company"], 
        request.filters["site"])

        if repo_type_error is not None:
            '''
                handle any get repo type system errors
            '''
            pass
        if repo_type == "Minestar Edge":
            edge_site, edge_key, edge_error = site_meta_data.get_edge_api_inputs(request.filters["parent_company"],
            request.filters["site"])
            ear = EdgeAPIRoutes(edge_site, edge_key)
            rl, routes_error = ear.get_route_list(request.filters["start_date"], 
            request.filters["end_date"])

            if routes_error is not None:
                '''
                    handle any get routes system error
                '''
                pass

            success_resp = response_objects.ResponseSuccess()
            success_resp.value = {"routes" : rl}

            return success_resp
    else:
        '''
            handle and errors due to an invalid request
        '''
        return response_objects.ResponseFailure.build_from_invalid_request_object(request)
```

**Result**

The assertions for the SiteMetaData patched methods pass while the assertions for the EdgeAPIRoutes class and methods fail. Based on the documentation, its seems both means of patching should have their assertions passing.

Comment: It depends on how you import the classes. In which module is `get_route_list` implemented? At a guess I would say that you do `from repo.routes import EdgeAPIRoutes`, and you have to patch `path_to_tested_module.EdgeAPIRoutes` (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)).

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly it. I also was missing this critical information from the documentation: "To configure return values on methods of instances on the patched class you must do this on the return_value (of the patched class)" [patch class method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrBeanBremen pointed out in his comment, where the classes are being patched is key. In my question, I was patching them at the source, but since they were imported into my interface.py file, they need to be patched in that location.

Also, since SiteMetaData is instantiated at the global level, its instance needs to be patched rather than the class itself. Since, EdgeAPIRoutes is instantiated within the get_route_list function, the class itself needs to be patched. Then to assign return values to the EdgeAPIRoutes's instance methods, the return_value of the patched class needs to be used:

```
mock_edge_api_routes_class.return_value.get_route_list.return_value = [                                                            
                                                                        example_route_list,                                                                        
                                                                        error_response                                                                   
                                                                      ]
```

Since the site_meta_data instance is patched directly, the instance method values can be assigned directly in the patch:

```
mock_site_meta_data.get_edge_api_inputs.return_value = [
                                                         edge_inputs["edge_site"], 
                                                         edge_inputs["edge_key"], 
                                                         error_response
                                                       ]
```

**interface.py**

```
import logging
from repo.site_meta_data import SiteMetaData
from repo.routes import EdgeAPIRoutes
from usecase import response_objects

interfacelog = logging.getLogger(__name__)

site_meta_data = SiteMetaData()

def get_route_list(request):
    """
    """

    interfacelog.info("running get_route_list")

    if bool(request):
        repo_type, repo_type_error = site_meta_data.get_repo_type(request.filters["parent_company"], 
        request.filters["site"])

        if repo_type_error is not None:
            '''
                handle any get repo type system errors
            '''
            pass
        if repo_type == "Minestar Edge":
            edge_site, edge_key, edge_error = site_meta_data.get_edge_api_inputs(request.filters["parent_company"],
            request.filters["site"])
            ear = EdgeAPIRoutes(edge_site, edge_key)
            rl, routes_error = ear.get_route_list(request.filters["start_date"], 
            request.filters["end_date"])

            if routes_error is not None:
                '''
                    handle any get routes system error
                '''
                pass

            success_resp = response_objects.ResponseSuccess()
            success_resp.value = {"routes" : rl}

            return success_resp
    else:
        '''
            handle and errors due to an invalid request
        '''
        return response_objects.ResponseFailure.build_from_invalid_request_object(request)
```

**test_interface function patch setup**

```
@patch("usecase.interface.EdgeAPIRoutes")
@patch("usecase.interface.site_meta_data")
def test_get_route_list_repo_interface_edge(self, mock_site_meta_data, 
mock_edge_api_routes_class):
    """
    Test that SiteMetaData.get_route_list is used 
    appropriately and returns expected values from 
    mock as a valid response object
    """
    ...
```